# Undefined references for mat.h in C

Tags: c, matlab, gcc, mingw

I'm trying to run the example code found in the examples folder within matlab's extern examples directory.

```
/*
 * Create a simple MAT-file to import into MATLAB.
 * Calling syntax:
 *
 *   matimport
 *
 * Simplified version of the matcreat.c program.
 * See the MATLAB External Interfaces Guide for 
 * compiling information.
 *
 * Copyright 2010 The MathWorks, Inc.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* For memcpy() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* For EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include "mat.h"

int main() {

  /* MAT-file */
  MATFile *pmat;
  const char *myFile = "matimport.mat";

  /* Data from external source */
  const char *extString = "Data from External Device";
  double extData[9] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 };

  /* Variables for mxArrays  */
  mxArray *pVarNum, *pVarChar;

  /* MATLAB variable names */
  const char *myDouble = "inputArray";
  const char *myString = "titleString";

  int status; 

  /* Create and open MAT-file */
  printf("Creating file %s...\n\n", myFile);
  pmat = matOpen(myFile, "w");
  if (pmat == NULL) {
    printf("Error creating file");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Create mxArrays and copy external data */
  pVarNum = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(3,3,mxREAL);
  if (pVarNum == NULL) {
      printf("Unable to create mxArray with mxCreateDoubleMatrix\n");
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  memcpy((void *)(mxGetPr(pVarNum)), (void *)extData, sizeof(extData));

  pVarChar = mxCreateString(extString);
  if (pVarChar == NULL) {
      printf("Unable to create mxArray with mxCreateString\n");
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Write data to MAT-file */
  status = matPutVariable(pmat, myString, pVarChar);
  if (status != 0) {
      printf("Error writing %s.\n", myString);
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } 

  status = matPutVariable(pmat, myDouble, pVarNum);
  if (status != 0) {
      printf("Error writing %s.\n", myDouble);
      return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }  

  if (matClose(pmat) != 0) {
    printf("Error closing file %s.\n", myFile);
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Clean up */
  mxDestroyArray(pVarNum);
  mxDestroyArray(pVarChar);

  printf("Done\n");
  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

But I get the following errors:

```
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\aashi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCh9dHA.o:main.c:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `matOpen_800'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\aashi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCh9dHA.o:main.c:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `mxCreateDoubleMatrix_800'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\aashi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCh9dHA.o:main.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `mxGetPr_800'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\aashi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCh9dHA.o:main.c:(.text+0xfb): undefined reference to `mxCreateString_800'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\aashi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCh9dHA.o:main.c:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `matPutVariable_800'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\aashi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCh9dHA.o:main.c:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `matPutVariable_800'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\aashi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCh9dHA.o:main.c:(.text+0x1af): undefined reference to `matClose_800'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\aashi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCh9dHA.o:main.c:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to `mxDestroyArray_800'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\aashi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccCh9dHA.o:main.c:(.text+0x1e6): undefined reference to `mxDestroyArray_800'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've used GCC to compile this program as follows:

```
gcc main.c -IC:/Progra~1/MATLAB/R2019a/extern/include -LC:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib -LC:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2019a\bin\win64\libmat.dll -o output
```

Any help?

Comment: You need `-l` to link the DLL, a lowercase letter L, not uppercase.

Comment: It says it cannot find libmat.dll when I do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to append `-lmx` or add `-lC:\Path\to\libmx.dll` in your gcc command. you may also need `-lmex -lm`

Comment: I get the following error: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2019a\bin\win64\libmx.dll

Comment: well, then you need to find where it is. install Everything Search (https://www.voidtools.com/) to find it quickly

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I know where the location is and for some reason it's not picking up the .dll files in the specified directory.

Comment: remove -l, just the dll file will link on windows.

Comment: It gives me the following error removing that, C:\Progra~1\MATLAB\R2019a\bin\win64\libmat.dll: file not recognized: file format not recognized

Comment: double quote the path, also you don't have to use the shortened path if you double quote the path.

Comment: Still no luck, gives me a file format not recognized error.

Comment: the better thing to do is to use `mex.bat -v -c main.c` to let matlab print the full compilation/linking commands. To do that, you must run `mex -setup C` in matlab to select the compilers.

Comment: So I got the following for the lib path: LINKLIBS : /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft" libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

How do I put this in my gcc compilation?

Comment: if you set up the mex C compiler as mingw64 c compiler, mex.bat -v should print the full gcc compilation/link command, that's what you should be using.

Comment: So I have it figured out and now it compiles and runs. But now it requires a lot of DLL files to be in the same directory as the output, is there any way to package this or organize it neatly?

Comment: @DumbCoder21: You need to add the path to the DLL files to the `PATH` environment variable before you run your executable.